# EntityFramework One-To-Many fK?

Tags: entity-framework

```
     BasketItem duplicateBasketItem = (from ph in storeDB.BasketItems
                                         where ph.sellerSKU == newItem.sellerSKU
                                         select ph).SingleOrDefault();
```

**{"Invalid column name 'BasketID'."}**

My Classes:

```
 public class Basket
{
    [Key]
    public string BasketID { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<BasketItem> BasketItems { get; set; }
    public int? Count { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
}


public class BasketItem
{
    [Key]
    public int BasketItemID { get; set; }

    public virtual string BasketID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int sellerID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string sellerSKU { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

}
```

From the research i have done so far, the error is being cause due to relationships not being mapped properly. How would I map the relationship using modelbuilder

Each basket can(optional) contain many basketitems

Each BasketItem has a BaskedID(FK) to map back to the individual Basket.

Comment: Code first, or DB first?

Comment: Code first.....,.,.,.,.,.,.

Comment: Are you sure the title should be `One-To-One fK`? This is just a plain one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Your virtual property in `BasketItem` should be this: `public virtual Basket Basket { get; set; }`

Comment: @DavidG you are correct, my mistake. This would be a One to many. One Basket - Many BasketItems

Comment: This should map without any explicit mapping. You should try and change the question if this model still gives problems.

Comment: @user1698144 Did you try my suggestion of changing the virtual property?

Comment: Was not able to get it to work that way. Each Basket contains a list of basketItems. Considering that, having each BaskItem contain a Basket would complicate matters even more. I was able to get past the error by not accessing the storeDB directly. Thanks for the assistance guys!